# Powershell 5: documentation support via comments for classes and enums members

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

Just wondering whether there is any support for comments considered as documentation for enums and classes members (methods and fields / properties) in PowerShell?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're referring to the equivalent of [Comment-Based Help](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comment_based_help), I've seen no indication of any. However, if you're writing classes or enums, you are also presumably writing scripts or script cmdlets/advanced functions that rely on them; it wouldn't be unreasonable to document the classes or enums in the scripts/etc. that use them.

Trevor Sullivan provides a link below to building your own `about_Topic` help data files; this represents another possibility, and one that may well be more appropriate, depending on how you're using your classes/enums.

Comment: You can also include conceptual `about_*` topics. https://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/trevor-powershell/Adding-Conceptual-Help-to-your-PowerShell-Modules

Comment: @TrevorSullivan - Interesting. Good to know, too.

Comment: I think @TrevorSullivan 's suggestion of using `about_*` topics is the correct way to do this (at this time).

Comment: Yes, I think that that's the way to go if there are multiple scripts/cmdlets/advanced functions using the same enums/classes. If it's just a one-off, though, I'd document as I indicated originally.